# options are not getting displayed in the select box

Tags: reactjs, json, object, react-hooks, jsx

My Goal: I want to build a conditional form where the user can set conditions on a particular value is selected, e.g. when a green color is chosen, show the "input box" or "input radio" or "checkbox input" etc.

[This is the conditional form where the user can set conditions to show any form element on choosing a particular element's value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFHPp.png)

The problem I'm facing: I'm using JSON schema to generate forms, user can add options dynamically to this JSON object. The options are being successfully added to json object, but are not displayed in the conditional form's dropdown with the label "Value".

> Down below is the JSON object defined in the useState hook.

```
const [select1, setSelect1] = useState({
    id: uuid(),
    type: 'select',
    properties: {
      label: 'Select1',
      options: [
        {
          id: uuid(),
          optionName: 'red ',
          value: '',
          childOptions: [],
        },
        {
          id: uuid(),
          optionName: 'green ',
          value: '',
          childOptions: [],
        },
        {
          id: uuid(),
          optionName: 'blue ',
          value: '',
          childOptions: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    parentId: null,
  });
```

[As you can see in the image, here are three dropdowns, the first dropdown has all the form elements, and the second dropdown with the label "Value" displays the options on the basis of the first dropdown's selection. This is where I'm facing issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzzG1.png)

> below is the code to add options in the object schema

```
   function addOptionsVal() {
    setElement2((prevState) => {
      const options = [
        ...prevState.properties.options,
        {
          id: uuid(),
          optionName: optionVal,
          value: '',
          childOptions: [],
        },
      ];
      return {
        ...prevState,
        properties: {
          ...prevState.properties,
          options,
        },
      };
    });
    setOptionVal('');
  }
```

[This is the entire code, in case you need to look](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yeisqp?file=src%2Findex.js,src%2FDynamicFields.jsx,src%2FSelect.jsx)